# Dynamic SQL Rolling 12 Months Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am new to Dynamic SQL. I have the following table:

| CustName | Date | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 01/01/2021 | 12 |
| Second | 01/01/2021 | 10 |
| Second | 05/02/2021 | 1 |
| Second | 10/11/2021 | 14 |

I am trying to make a rolling calendar Pivot for the last 12 months of summed hours.

Here is the code I have done:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF(
    (SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DATENAME(mm,Date) + ' of ' 
    + DATENAME(year,Date)) AS months_ago
          FROM [TimeEntryList]  
          WHERE Date > DATEADD(year, -1, 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')


 set @query = 'SELECT CustName, ' + @cols + ' 
 from ( select 
   [CustName], 
   datename(mm,[Date])+'' of ''+datename(year,[Date])AS 
   months_ago, [Hours] AS NetQty 
   from [TimeEntryList] 
    WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(year, -1, 
  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))
 ) as source 
 pivot 
 ( 
 sum(NetQty) For months_ago  in (' + @cols + ')
 ) as PivotTable'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

This works 'kind of' how I want it, but the columns are not ordered from current date backwards.

I'm wanting it to start at the current month backwards. So if this month is August it would be:

| CustName | Sep 2020 | .... months | August 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 12 |  | 14 |
| Second | 3 |  | 12 |

Is there a good way to start by current month in Dynamic SQL into a pivot and go back 12 months?

I tried 'order by months_ago desc' etc, but that doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You simply need to add a `WHERE` filter.** This needs to be in both parts of the query.

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DATENAME(mm, EOMONTH(Date)) + ' of ' + DATENAME(year, EOMONTH(Date))) AS months_ago
    FROM [TimeEntryList]  
    WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(year, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))
    GROUP BY EOMONTH(Date)
    ORDER BY EOMONTH(Date)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'');

SET @query = '
SELECT
  CustName,
  ' + @cols + ' 
from (
  select 
    [CustName], 
    datename(mm,[Date])+'' of ''+datename(year,[Date])AS months_ago, [Hours] AS 
    NetQty 
   from [TimeEntryList]
   WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(year, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))
 ) as source 
pivot 
  ( 
   sum(NetQty) For months_ago  in (' + @cols + ')
  ) as PivotTable;
';

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

You could even pass through a starting date parameter, like this:

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @dateFrom datetime;

SET @dateFrom = DATEADD(year, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1));

SET @cols = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DATENAME(mm,EOMONTH(Date)) + ' of ' + DATENAME(year,EOMONTH(Date)) AS months_ago
    FROM [TimeEntryList]  
    WHERE [Date] > @dateFrom
    GROUP BY EOMONTH(Date)
    ORDER BY EOMONTH(Date)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'');

SET @query = '
SELECT
  CustName,
  ' + @cols + ' 
from (
  select 
    [CustName], 
    datename(mm,[Date])+'' of ''+datename(year,[Date])AS months_ago, [Hours] AS 
    NetQty 
   from [TimeEntryList]
   WHERE [Date] > @dateFrom
 ) as source 
pivot 
  ( 
   sum(NetQty) For months_ago  in (' + @cols + ')
  ) as PivotTable;
';

execute sp_executesql
    @query
    N'@dateFrom datetime',
    @dateFrom = @dateFrom;
```

Comment: Ah - thanks. For some reason I'm getting 'QUOTENAME' is not an in-built function. If I wrap that in brackets it fixes it, but the report just executes and doesn't display data.

Comment: I edited my answer, thank you! I think the main issue is, is that I'm trying to get the last column as the current month, with the columns rolling backwards by month

Comment: I think it comes down to ordering by the 'dynamic' part. I know how to order by date in regular SQL, but with this dynamic example I think I need to try and order on 'months_ago' which won't work. Maybe I need to create a temp pivot table first, then use dynamic SQL ... maybe .. kind of new to this.

Comment: Thanks! - I have created one [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7535ac0f61753ec6a8873f661be93114)  As you can see, April 2021 is showing up first.

Comment: OK fixed that for you https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1f02467a595480b0b772d89c0897d05

Comment: THANK YOU!! Really appreciate it!